# HTML5 VIDEO tag correct source using PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, video, src

I would like to use **video** tag in my PhoneGap app for playing inapp stored file. Unfortunately, I am not able to find a way, how to address the file. When I define my tag externally as

```
<video controls id="introVideo">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

everything works fine (it's the same when I load the file to permanent storage in the device and I play it from there). When I do i like this

```
<source src="/www/graphics/video/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>
```

there is a JS ERROR "Failed to load resource small.mp4" and the video player show video length 0:00. When I do it like this

```
<source src="file:///android_asset/www/graphics/video/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>
```

there is no error, but video length shown by the video player is 1:40 (originally it's 0:05) and clicking play button does nothing.

Output from my file location function

```
FA.getInAppFilePath = function(filePath,successCallback, failCallback)
{
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + filePath, function (fileEntry) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
     }, failCallback);
}
```

console output:

```
{
   "isFile":true,
   "isDirectory":false,
   "name":"small.mp4",
   "fullPath":"/www/graphics/video/small.mp4",
   "filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>",
   "nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/www/graphics/video/small.mp4"
}
```

so, it proves the file is located on the mobile device. Here you can see screenshot of the videoplayer from 3 examples mentioned above:

[image]

Any idea, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The path should be `<source src="graphics/video/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>` 
You're already in /www

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the first option I tried - it gives the same result as file:/// syntax - video length 1:40 and no playback.